# Problems when dismissing a modal UIViewController with a UITableView in it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

So I have a `UIViewController` that I'm presenting over the current view modally. This view controller consists only of a `UITableView` (for selecting items), and a navigation bar at the top which has a Cancel button in case you don't want to select anything.

The whole thing works just fine in almost any situation. Selecting an item works, pressing the cancel button dismisses the view, everything is fine. However, there's one case that causes the app to crash: when you swipe left on an item in the table view to reveal the delete button, then press the cancel button at the top to dismiss the view, the app crashes and it doesn't say anything about the cause of the crash in the console output. Here's the code for the view controller I'm presenting modally:

.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "common.h"

@interface LoadViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

- (IBAction)lCancelButton:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *lTableView;

@end
```

.m:

```
#import "LoadViewController.h"

@interface LoadViewController () {
    NSMutableArray* sampleCounts;
    NSArray* tableData;
}
@end

@implementation LoadViewController

@synthesize lTableView = _lTableView;  // This is the table view itself

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        // Deleting an item when the delete button is pressed

        [self.lTableView beginUpdates];

        // Deleting it from the table view first
        [self.lTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

        // ... then from the arrays as well
        [sampleCounts removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
        // (making a mutable copy here so I can delete stuff from it)
        NSMutableArray* tmp = [tableData mutableCopy];
        [tmp removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
        tableData = tmp;

        [self.lTableView endUpdates];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.lTableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = NO;
    sampleCounts = [NSMutableArray array];
    tableData = [NSMutableArray array];

    // I'm filling up both arrays with the appropriate data here...

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (IBAction)lCancelButton:(id)sender {
    // Dismiss the view controller when Cancel is pressed
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.tableData.count;
}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // If an item gets selected, store the name of it (I use a class called 'common' for storing data like this), then dismiss the view
    [common setItemName:[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString* ID = @"ID";
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ID];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:ID];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [sampleCounts objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

So as you can see, it's very simple. I have the item names and the descriptions of them in two separate arrays (both arrays hold `NSString*`s), I fill up the table view with that information, and that's it. The rest is pretty straight forward.

So does anyone have any idea why the app crashes when I swipe on an item to reveal the delete button, and then dismiss the view controller by pressing Cancel? In every other case, everything works perfectly fine. It only crashes when I press Cancel whenever a delete button is visible.

Comment: Did you try to add an exceptional break point?

Comment: Or what information did XCode print to the console?

Comment: Absolutely nothing gets printed out. That's my problem really, because I have no idea what's wrong. Nothing is printed to the console, the app simply stops hanging on the `return` line in main.m, saying `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

Comment: So, try what I just posted. Because the differences is you are in the editing mode or not.

Comment: I just saw it -_-. That's fine. Because you only crash on the editing mode. That might be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.lTableView.editing = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I can think of is about your mode.
Probably is you are in the editing mode.
So, try to go back to the normal mode before dismissing.

```
[self.tableView setEditing:No];
```